# Обращение к серверу без node.js

Tags: php, ajax

Я никак не пойму одну вещь. Допустим на сервере нет node.js, но ajax посылает запросы на определенный PHP обработчик и генерирует требуемый ответ, то все ведь будет работать?

Если нет то что именно мешает этому способу?

Comment: **nodejs** и **ajax** это не связанные технологи

Comment: т.е они могу быть использованы отдельно

Comment: @Kison я читал в учебнике javascript они использовали именно этот способ. Но вопрос поставлен иначе. Какие технологии и как можно использовать вместе с ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно понять цели использования **ajax**. Вкратце он необходим для того чтобы была возможность получать некие данные с сервера асинхронно, т.е без перезагрузки страницы в целом. Каждое веб приложение состоит из клиентской части (набор html, css, js) и серверной (Работа с базой данных, генерация разметки и т.д). Представим что нам нужно обновить контент некоего блока на нашем веб сайте, для этого наш клиент отправит **ajax** запрос на сервер и будет ждать ответ, при этом ему все равно какой именно язык будет генерировать ответ, это может быть **с#, php, python, node, go**.

Comment: Отлично, это я и хотел увидеть. Это вполне логично и меня все время терзала мысль что это возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js-это в моем понимании библиотека для работы с сервером через JS.
С помощью node.js пишут замену php обработчика.Но ajax не знает,что вы используете php,node.js,python и др.
Ajax посылает запрос на сервер и получает информацию с него,то есть
ничего не мешает,ajax работает без node.js и с ним тоже может.
P.s.Я новичок могу ошибаться.

Comment: Добавьте в свой ответ больше конкретики